# Using Material Design with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, material-design-lite

I am trying to use [MDL](https://www.getmdl.io/) in my Angular 2 app. Basically, I have a dashboard with several tabs. However, when I render the tabs, it breaks. Following is my code:

`dashboard.html`

```
<header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Dashboard</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <a [routerLink]="['tab1']" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">tab1</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['tab2']"  class="mdl-layout__tab">tab2</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['tab3']" class="mdl-layout__tab">tab3</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['tab4']" class="mdl-layout__tab">Netflix tab4</a>
    </div>
</header>

<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

</div>
```

`dashboard.component.ts`

```
declare var componentHandler: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'millvi-dashboard-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/dashboard/dashboard.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class DashboardComponent {

 constructor(el: ElementRef){
     componentHandler.upgradeElement(el.nativeElement);
 }
}
```

The above doesn't render properly. I have tried to use `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` instead of `componentHandler.upgradeElement(el.nativeElement)`.

It renders correctly, but on clicking the tabs I get the following error

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
angular2.dev.js:23514 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of nullBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23525ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1145(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700r.run @ angular2-polyfills.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.min.js:1
angular2.dev.js:23514 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1147(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700r.run @ angular2-polyfills.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.min.js:1
angular2.dev.js:23514 TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js:8:1465)
    at r.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js:1:1996)
    at r.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:5719:32)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js:1:1720)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manipulate DOM from the Component constructor, as that component of DOM isn't rendered. You should wait till content gets render.

For that you need to implement the lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit()` by implementing class with `AfterViewInit` to component class.

import{ Component, AfterViewInit } from 'angular2/core'

```
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    element: ElementRef;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.element = el;
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(el: ElementRef) {
        componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.element.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this

`export class DashboardComponent {
    element : ElementRef;

 constructor(el: ElementRef){
     this.element = el;

 }
    ngAfterViewInit(el: ElementRef){
        componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.element.nativeElement);
    }
}`

Comment: @user3288346 you need to import `AfterViewInit ` hook from `angular2/core`, try updated..

Comment: I did that and even included a `console.log` inside ngAfterViewInit(). I t prints, but ui breaks.